# How do I return a relative HTML table value?

Tags: javascript, html, parent-child

I have an HTML table with buttons in the fourth column. I want to be able to push each button and have it return the value in the second column, but same row.

I create the table using this code:

```js
function loadTableData() {
    for (i=0; i < 7; i++) {
        let row = table.insertRow();
        let scale = row.insertCell(0);
        let note = row.insertCell(1);
        let chord = row.insertCell(2);
        let play = row.insertCell(3);
        scale.innerHTML = degChoice[i]
        note.innerHTML = finalArray[i];
        chord.innerHTML = chordChoice[i];
        play.innerHTML = '<button onclick="playAudio()">Play Chord</button>'
    }
}
```

The table values are being generated based on other criteria (this part's working fine).

And this is the code I am using to try to call the value of the second cell in the row:

```js
function playAudio(){
    var firstCell = this.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes[1].nodeValue;
    alert(firstCell);
}
```

No matter what I try, I can't return that second cell value. Does anyone have any advice for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning the event handler wrong. Generally you should avoid using `on...` attributes, but if you do it, you need to pay attention to how `this` is assigned a value.

It is defined inside the `onclick`, but not inside your function `playAudio`, so you will need to pass it on:

```
play.innerHTML = '<button onclick="playAudio(this)">Play Chord</button>'
```

```
function playAudio(button){
  var firstCell = button.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes[1].nodeValue;
  alert(firstCell);
}
```

However alternativly you can use `this` inside `playAudio` if you assign it directly as the event handler, but then you'll need to create the button as a DOM element:

```
const button = document.createElement("button");
button.textContent = "Play Chord"; // Use textContent instead of innerHtml when assigning plain text
button.addEventListener("click", playAudio); // or: button.onclick = playAudio;
play.appendChild(button);
```

Now you can use `this` inside `playAudio`. Or, even better access the event object as the first parameter inside `playAudio`:

```
function playAudio(event){
  var button = event.target; // or: var button = this;
  var firstCell = button.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes[1].nodeValue;
  alert(firstCell);
}
```

Intoduction to events: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events